# Get child element on click - Vue JS

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

I need an equivalent of jQuery "this.find()" to get child element from this section on click.

So on click="showProd(6) I want to find "this .dropProd" inside a method ":

[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EGcGC.png)

```
<div class="sections" @click="showProd(6)">
  <h2 class="padding-10">Limited Shelf Life</h2>
  <div class="dropProd" :class="{ activate : active_el == 6}">
    <div v-for="item in shelf" :key="item.id" class="niceBox">
      <p class="prod_title">{{item.title}}</p>
      <p class="prod_info">{{item.product_details}}</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [$refs](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-edge-cases.html#Accessing-Child-Component-Instances-amp-Child-Elements):

```
<div class="sections" @click="showProd(6)">
  <h2 class="padding-10">Limited Shelf Life</h2>
   <!-- note the ref attribute below here -->
  <div ref="dropProd" class="dropProd" :class="{ activate : active_el == 6}">
    <div v-for="item in shelf" :key="item.id" class="niceBox">
      <p class="prod_title">{{item.title}}</p>
      <p class="prod_info">{{item.product_details}}</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Access it in `<script>` via `this.$refs.dropProd`

Answer (score 0):

You could just use this.$refs with an appropriate reference name inside your function like this:

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: function() {
    return {

    }
  },
  methods: {
    showProd(){
      console.log(this.$refs.referenceMe);
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>

<div id="app">

  <div class="sections"style="background-color: red" @click="showProd(6)">
    <h2 class="padding-10">Limited Shelf Life</h2>
    <div class="dropProd" ref="referenceMe">

    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```